# ROC curve in R using rpart package?

Tags: r, classification, predict, roc

I split `Train` data set and `Test` data set.

I used a package `rpart` for CART (classification tree) in R (only train set). And I want to carry out a ROC analysis using the `ROCR` package.

Variable is `n. use' (response varible... 1=yes, 0=no):

```
> Pred2 = prediction(Pred.cart, Test$n.use)
Error in prediction(Pred.cart, Test$n.use) : 
  **Format of predictions is invalid.**
```

This is my code. What is problem? And what is right `type` (`"class"` or `"prob"`?

```
library(rpart)
train.cart = rpart(n.use~., data=Train, method="class")

Pred.cart = predict(train.cart, newdata = Test, type = "class")

Pred2 = prediction(Pred.cart, Test$n.use)
roc.cart = performance(Pred2, "tpr", "fpr")
```

Answer (score 10):

The `prediction()` function from the `ROCR` package expects the predicted "success" probabilities and the observed factor of failures vs. successes. In order to obtain the former you need to apply `predict(..., type = "prob")` to the `rpart` object (i.e., *not* `"class"`). However, as this returns a matrix of probabilities with one column per response class you need to select the "success" class column.

As your example, unfortunately, is not reproducible I'm using the `kyphosis` data from the `rpart` package for illustration:

```
library("rpart")
data("kyphosis", package = "rpart")
rp <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis)
```

Then you can apply the `prediction()` function from `ROCR`. Here, I'm using the in-sample (training) data but the same can be applied out of sample (test data):

```
library("ROCR")
pred <- prediction(predict(rp, type = "prob")[, 2], kyphosis$Kyphosis)
```

And you can visualize the ROC curve:

```
plot(performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr"))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

Or the accuracy across cutoffs:

```
plot(performance(pred, "acc"))
```

Or any of the other plots and summaries supported by `ROCR`.

[image: ROCR plots]

Comment: Awesome answer! Where do you get all this knowledge?

Comment: Also what is 'success' class? For `kyphosis` data set it is fairly obvious `present` case, but if we are working with `a` and `b` outcomes. Which one should be designate as success?

Comment: Your choice. Both would work and you can choose which one you find easier to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

```
library("ROCR")
Pred.cart = predict(train.cart, newdata = Test, type = "prob")[,2] 
Pred2 = prediction(Pred.cart, Test$n.use) 
plot(performance(Pred2, "tpr", "fpr"))
abline(0, 1, lty = 2)
```

This snippet will work for you.

for more details refer to link :
[Classification Trees (R)](http://scg.sdsu.edu/ctrees_r/)